# Is there step-by-step tutorial on setting up CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

What to do automatic nightly build of .NET web application and upload to the test server.

Or, if this tool is overkill, please suggest something else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found this great tutorial: [How to Hook Up a VS.NET 2005 Solution With CruiseControl.NET in a Few Minutes](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/pages/How-to-Hook-Up-a-VS.NET-2005-Solution-With-CruiseControl.NET-in-a-Few-Minutes.aspx).
It's short but uses a real .Net project to illustrate the set up.

After that refine your configuration by reading each relevant section of [CruiseControl.NET : Configuring the Server](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuring+the+Server)

And for a really nice and recent tutorial check [Integrating MSBuild with CruiseControl.NET](http://www.dougrohm.com/blog/post/2006/01/29/Integrating-MSBuild-with-CruiseControlNET.aspx). Very good one!

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are all great, but have you also looked at [CI Factory](http://cifactory.org/joomla/)? From the CI Factory site:

> CI Factory is a Continuous Integration
>   system, not just a CI server.  With
>   minimal configuration it creates a CI
>   system for you including much of your
>   development environment.  It will
>   create a development tree, write your
>   build scripts, setup a super powered
>   version of CruiseControl.Net, import
>   it all into source control, and more. 
>   It does all the work that everyone has
>   to do when creating a CI system.  It
>   even has automated branch creation
>   baked in, so the next time you need to
>   create a branch for a release, CI
>   Factory will handle that for you.

Answer (score 2):

[CruiseControl.NET From Scratch](http://joefield.mysite4now.com/blogs/blog/articles/146.aspx)

Its a great tool, we use it here todo hourly builds and manage multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

I used the instructions and example on the CruiseControl.Net website

[Setting up from scratch Part 01](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Setting+up+from+scratch++Part+01).

Comment: Apparently Part 01 is the only part. And the example in it is too primitive.